# Int cannot be referenced

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to split two integers from a single input into two different int variables. For example, the input will be formatted as 11 2 or 1027 -11. There will always be a space between these numbers.

```
//prompt for X and Z
System.out.println("Please enter values for X and Z: ");
// breaking apart X and Z
int XZ = kb.nextInt();
int [] var = XZ.split(" ");
```

I get the error that the int cannot be dereferenced when I try to make XZ into a split array. Is there an easier way to split these variables?

Comment: You said there would be a space between the numbers but then you use a single nextInt() to grab the input which doesn't make sense.  You'd either need two nextInt() calls, or maybe a nextLine() (which returns a String) followed by a split(" ") call

Answer (score 2):

[split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method is found in string class

Answer (score 1):

[`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method  is  in `String` class

Just change the `nextInt()` to `nextLine()`

```
   String XZ = kb.nextLine();
   String [] var = XZ.split(" ");
   int intvariables=new intvariable[var.length];
   for(int i=0;i<var.length;i++)
     {
      intvariables[i]=Integer.parseInt(var[i]);
     }
```